# Server can not accept argument. FTP upload in shell

Tags: php, upload, arguments

```
    $local = 'WP_Inv.csv';
    $remote = 'WP_Inv.csv';
    $user = "User861";
    $pass = "topsecret";
    $host = 'ftp.server.com';
    $port = '21';
    $timeout = '90';
    $type = FTP_ASCII;

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($host,$port,$timeout);

    $login = ftp_login($conn_id, $user, $pass);

             ftp_put($conn_id, $remote, $local, $type);
```

returning the following error when ran from shell:

The very last line is showing an error, any help would be great I am pulling my hair out!

PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): Server cannot accept argument.

(Yes I close my connection later in the code)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried turning on passive mode? I've had the same issue in the past and its because the machine running the php code and the ftp server could not handshake on an active connection.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php

```
bool ftp_pasv ( resource $ftp_stream , bool $pasv )
ftp_pasv() turns on or off passive mode. In passive mode, data connections are initiated by the client, rather than by the server. It may be needed if the client is behind firewall.

Please note that ftp_pasv() can only be called after a successfull login or otherwise it will fail.
```